# How to use `runAccumT`

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to replace `StateT` with `AccumT` in my program but I can't figure out exactly how it works. Specifically, I don't understand why `runAccumT` and its derivatives seem to ignore their second argument. For example, I was expecting

```hs
execAccumT (add 7) 8 :: IO Int
```

to print `15`, but it prints `7`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Updated* with a workaround.

First, note that `Accum` uses a general `Monoid`, not just a sum, so even though your code happens to work because it involves only one monadic `add`, anything that actually involved multiple accumulator operations would fail to type check:

```
> execAccumT (add 7 >> add 8) 0 :: IO Int
<interactive>:39:19-20: error:
    • No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of ‘>>’
    ...
```

Instead, as in @DanielWagner's answer, you need to use the `Sum` monoid:

```
> execAccumT (add 7 >> add 8) 0 :: IO (Sum Int)
Sum {getSum = 15}
```

You can continue to write `add 7` instead of `add (Sum 7)` because `Sum Int` has a `Num` instance that automatically converts numeric literatals to sums, and allows simple arithmetic operations on them, but if you wanted to `add x` where `x :: Int`, you'd need to write `add (Sum x)` explicitly.

Second, there does appear to be a bug in the handling of the initial value of the accumulator, what the documentation calls its "initial history".  If you write:

```
> execAccumT (add 7 >> add 8) 999 :: IO (Sum Int)
```

it appears that the initial history is ignored, but if you use `runAccumT` to simultaneously inspect both what `look` thinks is the final history, and the final history returned by `runAccumT`, you can see a discrepancy:

```
λ> runAccumT (add 7 >> add 8 >> look) 999 :: IO (Sum Int, Sum Int)
(Sum {getSum = 1014},Sum {getSum = 15})
```

That is, `look`'s opinion of the final history is that it includes the initial history, but the final history returned by `runAccumT` doesn't include the initial history.

For now, it's safe to use `Accum` with an "`mempty`" initial history, i.e., whatever is the appropriate zero value for the `Monoid`, and use an initial `add` operation if you want to start with something other than `mempty`.

If you want to use a non-`mempty` history, I suggest importing with a few functions hidden and use these replacements:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.Accum hiding (runAccum, execAccum, runAccumT, execAccumT)

runAccumT :: (Functor m, Monoid w) => AccumT w m a -> w -> m (a,w)
runAccumT (AccumT f) w = (\(a, w') -> (a, w <> w')) <$> f w

execAccumT :: (Monad m, Monoid w) => AccumT w m a -> w -> m w
execAccumT m = fmap snd . runAccumT m

runAccum :: (Monoid w) => Accum w a -> w -> (a, w)
runAccum m = runIdentity . runAccumT m

execAccum :: (Monoid w) => Accum w a -> w -> w
execAccum m = snd . runAccum m
```

These should work fine:

```
λ> runAccumT (add 7 >> add 8 >> look) 999 :: IO (Sum Int, Sum Int)
(Sum {getSum = 1014},Sum {getSum = 1014})
```

Comment: I submitted [issue #92](https://hub.darcs.net/ross/transformers/issue/92).

Comment: Probably the right fix is simply not to expose the extra `w` argument in the API, i.e. have `runAccumT act = realRunAccumT act mempty` etc. It seems like this implementation strategy doesn't make much sense otherwise, the discrepancy between "input accumulation" and "output accumulation" is just too weird.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I think it can be fixed up at the back end.  Right now, `runAccumT` just unwraps the `w -> (a, w)` newtype, but it actually needs to apply that operation to the initial history and *then* `mappend` the initial and returned histories to get the final history.

Comment: Ah, nice. Yeah, that would probably fix everything up.

Comment: With the help of GitHub Copilot I managed to roll [my own `AccumT`](https://github.com/roninbar/nim/blob/accum/src/Main/Trans/Accum.hs) which works as expected and also has `instance (Monad m, Monoid w) => MonadAccum w (AccumT w m)` for every monad `m` rather than just for `Identity`.
`

Comment: @RonInbar Note that those `Applicative` and `Monad` instances don't accumulate the output monoidally -- they amount to (strict) `StateT` rather than `AccumT`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a workaround.

Comment: @duplode I'm trying to change it according to your comment but I keep getting the wrong results. I feel like such a novice trying to debug Haskell code...

Comment: @duplode How about [now](https://github.com/roninbar/nim/blob/accum/src/Main/Trans/Accum.hs)?

Comment: @RonInbar Those instances look okay now. By the way, though I might be missing something, I don't get why `Control.Monad.Accum` from *mtl* defines just the `Monoid w => MonadAccum w (AccumT w Identity)` instance, rather than  `(Monad m, Monoid w) => MonadAccum w (AccumT w m)`.

Comment: @RonInbar P.S.: On the `MonadAccum` instance, it seems that will get sorted out in *mtl* eventually -- see [PR #141](https://github.com/haskell/mtl/pull/141).

Comment: @duplode Yes, I'm aware of that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Only three base actions inspect the incoming accumulated value: `accum`, `look`, and `looks`. So if you want the argument to `runAccumT`, you must explicitly ask for it using one of those as your very first action.

```
> execAccumT (look >>= add) 7 :: IO (Sum Int)
Sum {getSum = 7}
```

It does seem a bit odd.